# where does the value for the _doc come from when sort in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using 7.10.1, and I have put into the index with the following data:

```
PUT /lib15/_doc/1
{
  "price":32

}



PUT /lib15/_doc/2
{
  "price":21
}



PUT /lib15/_doc/3
{
  "price":48
}

PUT /lib15/_doc/4
{
  "price":40
}

PUT /lib15/_doc/5
{
  "price":42
}
```

Then I do the following query,

```
GET /lib15/_search
{
"size": 2,
"query": {
"match_all": {}
},
"sort": [
{
"price": "desc"
},
{
"_doc": "desc"
}
]
}
```

The result is:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "lib15",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 48
        },
        "sort" : [
          48,
          2
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "lib15",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 42
        },
        "sort" : [
          42,
          4
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would ask `2` and `4` in `"sort":[48,2] and "sort":[42,4]` come from? Are they _doc value? but they are not equal to the _id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation of sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html), `_doc` is used to sort by index order.

it means your document containing price was indexed in 2nd and price containing document was indexed in 4th order.

**Update:**, I used the same order of insertion which you provided and was able to get the same order which you provided, although in the example we are indexing `price:48` in 3rd and `price:42` in 5th order, but when you use the `GET` api with these document-id, it prints the `_seq_no` which is 2 and 4 as shown below:

GET http://localhost:9900/lib15/_doc/3

```
{
    "_index": "lib15",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 2, // note for id 3, seq_no is 2
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "price": 48
    }
}
```

And GET http://localhost:9900/lib15/_doc/5

```
{
    "_index": "lib15",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "5",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 4, // // note for id 5, seq_no is 4
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "price": 42
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @opster-elasticsearch-ninja for the great explanation and help, I understand now